# Performance Testing Mainframe ERP system - baseline

Tags: load, performance-testing, load-testing

newbie in performance testing. Have a client who wants to have performance testing done on their ERP system which is mainframe.

They have 3 environments: 1 dev and one pre-prod that will become prod at some point and of course production

Im thinking of JMeter here. I has some exposure to it years back

Question 1: Can I use JMeter to test mainframe ERP?

Question 2: I need to take a baseline test. Is it normally done in production?

Question 3: If the client does not know their SLAs at all. They want me to help them what are some  of the steps to take to figure out what those should be. Also how do you come up with scenarios to test?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

1. JMeter per se cannot, however it's possible with [JMeter-RTE-plugin](https://github.com/Blazemeter/RTEPlugin#jmeter-rte-plugin), check out [Testing Mainframe Environments Using Open-Source Tools](https://www.blazemeter.com/solutions/mainframe) for more information
2. "Baseline" is a reference test and/or test result. For example you executed a [stress test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing), identified bottlenecks, raised issues, fixed issues, repeated test, repeated the whole flow and at some point you're happy with your system performance and consider it acceptable. In this case you would run a [load test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Load_testing) to measure the metrics of the reference build. Then you repeat the tests against new builds and compare them with the baseline, if there is a performance degradation - you will be informed.

   Normally people don't test in production, especially when it comes to potentially destructive testing types they use production-like environments.
3. If there are no SLAs - you can suggest the aforementioned stress test to identify the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html).

Comment: thank you! Great info. What sort of questions you think are appropriate for me ask? Like what is expected load of the system, like number of users at the same time? What servers and network looks like?